# Selenium login time- Am I calculating right?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have searched quite a bit on how to get login time but could not find any definitive answer.  I do not want to introduce any timers in my scripts.  My aim is to find how much time it took exactly to login and logout in my selenium script.

I have following so far-

I am getting start time and finish time and getting the login  time as follows-

```
public void testLogin(){
```

String csvFile = "C:\Users\users.csv";

```
BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = ",";

try {

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
        String[] value = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

        WebDriver driver =  new HtmlUnitDriver();
        //WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("www.test.com"); 
        long start=System.currentTimeMillis();

        driver.findElement(By.id("txt-username")).sendKeys(value[0]);
        driver.findElement(By.id("pwd-password")).sendKeys(value[1]);
        driver.findElement(By.id("login-widget-submit")).click();


        long finish=System.currentTimeMillis();
        long OverallTime =finish-start;
        System.out.println("Total time for login -"+OverallTime);

        driver.close()
```

Comment: Please take a minute to properly format your code so that it's easier to read.

Comment: You mention wanting to get page load time but you also talk about essentially script run time... which is it that you want? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I want to know how much time the application taking to login

Comment: Please update your question and the description to reflect what you are asking so everyone doesn't have to read the comments for clarification.

Comment: updated the post, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only measure the time taken to log in (not to load the login page and then log in), you will want to add a `WebDriverWait` after `driver.get()` and wait for a specific element to load to ensure that the page is fully loaded. You will want to add another wait after clicking Submit to ensure that the page after login has loaded completely. That is a better test of login time. What you have now is you start the timer potentially before the login page is loaded and then stop the timer when you click the Submit button... but the user isn't actually logged in yet.

I personally use the `StopWatch` class that's a part of `apache.commons` to do timings.

Comment: I want to record time= load login page + login , do I use StopWatch then?

Comment: You don't have to use StopWatch, you can do the timing yourself but the StopWatch class is easy to use, gets the job done, and has been tested thoroughly.